# Question on Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds 1-1

Tags: manifolds

The question is:

Prove that $|x| \le \sum_{i=0}^n |x^i|$

But the solution has this step:

$ (\sum_{i=0}^n |x^i|)^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n (x^i)^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} x^ix^j   $

How is this true?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg What about the addition??

Comment: For example, $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2 + ab + ba$ and $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + ac + bc + ba + bc + ba + bc$.

Comment: @angryavian so does i and j in what's being added represent all the possible cases depending on the variable? For example, would it represent the (+ab+ac+bc+ba+bc+ba+bc)?

Comment: Yes, the "$i \ne j$" is shorthand for "all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $0 \le i \le n$ and $0 \le j \le n$ and $i \ne j$."

Comment: Just work out an example for small n. This is a fairly standard trick so it's worth understanding in detail. BTW, I think you've left out the absolute value signs in the second sum on the RHS.

Comment: @Nick Thank you! I'm having trouble coming up with an example in which $ |x| $ would be greater than, though.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you!

Comment: $|x|$ would be greater than what?

Comment: @Nick I'm sorry, I meant less than $\sum_{i=0}^n|x^i|$

Comment: Try $x=(1, 2, 3)$. Then $|x| = \sqrt{14}$ and $\sum_i |x^i| = 1+2 + 3 = 6$.